# SwipeRefreshLayout with Webview not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview, swiperefreshlayout

This is my webview app code with SwipeRefreshLayout. But SwipeRefresh not working please check it. But all other things are working correctly. Like webview, menu button.

Below is my activity_main.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my `MainActivity.java` file

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu manu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, manu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        int id=item.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.id_about){
            Intent intentabout=new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
            startActivity(intentabout);

            return true;
        }
        if(id==R.id.id_terms){

            return true;
        }
        if(id==R.id.id_privacy){

            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                LoadWeb();
            }
        });

        LoadWeb();

    }

    public void LoadWeb(){
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");

            }

            public void onPagefinished(WebView view, String url){
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You can refer to the following https://github.com/zhangle1/HelpText/tree/master/app/src

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You gotta put your WebView inside SwipeRefreshLayout:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    String currentUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);

        webView.loadUrl(currentUrl);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.loadUrl(currentUrl);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            currentUrl = url;
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }
}
```

swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false) stops the animation.

Comment: Thanks Harshil. Now its work. Thank you very much. Now i have one question how to show the loading wheel on  initial webview loading.

Comment: here i have added loading wheel when initialing webview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407308/loading-wheel-on-initial-webview-loading/44407309#44407309

Answer (score 5):

you can put your Webview inside a `NestedScrollView` to make this work.

Example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipe"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: not necessary to nest nestedscrollview anymore, swiperefreshlayout inherits from NestedScrollingParent and NestedScrollingChild

Comment: This is a complete solution! with the right swiping behaviour. This should be the accepted Answer!

Answer (score 2):

You should add

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            LoadWeb();
        }
    });
    swipe.setRefreshing(true); //add
    LoadWeb();

}
LoadWeb();
```

Comment: You need to change the refresh state to true automatically so that the Loading will display

Comment: Try deleting RelativeLayout or trying to upgrade your compatible package version to compile'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

Comment: Deleting the RelativeLayout not showing any difference. I am completly new this. plz point out how to upgrade compatible package version. In my build.gradle shows compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

Comment: You should modify the Android {compileSdkVersion 25}