# Loading wheel on initial webview loading

Tags: android, webview, loading

In android how can i show loading wheel on initial **webview** loading?

**webview** doesn't show loading when initializing webview in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public AppWebViewClients(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.progressBar=progressBar;
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

I think it help you.

Thanks.